# How to get all values from list created by immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, immutability, immutable.js

I created array by Immutable.js

```
var list = Immutable.List([ 1, 2, 3 ]);

list.push('333');

// this does not show list
console.log(list);
```

How to get all values?

Because console.log(list); does not work.

Comment: No, just see [ 1, 2, 3 ] in console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With push you create new list. Then it last element is '333'

Console.log(list) will print internal representation of list that is quite verbose. Use last or map.

```
var list = Immutable.List([ 1, 2, 3 ]);
let newList = list.push('333');

// print last element
console.log(newList.last())

// print all elements
newList.map((e)=> console.log(e))
```

Or you can use toJS() to create ordinary javascript array from immutable array. And then print it.

Comment: I don't want to iterate this list.
I want to print it wholly. And without '333'.